# Injected function into a class constructor throws undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I am learning about using typescript to build API's, I have come across two issues right now. First, I have a somewhat generic PostController Class that can accept a use-case that implements the PostMethod Interface, e.g

```
export interface PostMethod {
  add: (req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<any> // not sure if it should be returning any
}
```

That's the interface, and the generic controller looks like this.

```
export class PostController implements PostMethod {
  constructor(public postMethod: any) {}

  async add(req: Request, res: Response) {
    let { ...incomingHttpBody } = req.body
    console.log('body', incomingHttpBody)
    console.log(this.postMethod)
    type Source = {
      ip: string
      browser: string | string[] | undefined
      referrer: string | string[]
    }
    let source = {} as Source
    source.ip = req.ip
    source.browser = req.headers['User-Agent']
    if (req.headers.Referer) {
      source.referrer = req.headers.Referer
    }
    const newItem = await this.postMethod({ source, ...incomingHttpBody })
    return apiResponse({
      status: true,
      statusCode: 201,
      message: 'Resource created successfully',
      data: [newItem]
    })
  }
}
```

And then, I can use this `PostController` class like this

```
...
const postMethod = new AddUser(UsersDb).addUser
export const postUser = new PostController(postMethod)
...
```

The `AddUser` class looks like this,

```
export class AddUser {
  constructor(public usersDb: UserDatabase) {}

  async addUser(userInfo: IUser) {
    console.log({...userInfo})
    const exists = await this.usersDb.findByEmail(userInfo.email)
    if (exists) {
      throw new UniqueConstraintError('Email address')
    }
    const user = new UserFactory(userInfo)
    user.makeUser()
    const { email, ...details } = user.user
    const newUser = await this.usersDb.insert({ email, ...details })
    const id = newUser.user._id
    await createWallet(id)
    // await publisher(id.toString(), 'newuser.verify')
    // await consumer('verify_queue', verifyUser, '*.verify')
    return newUser
  }
}
```

When I do a console.log of req.body, I get the incoming body, but I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMethod' of undefined`. I am unsure how to annotate the constructor function also. I do not know what I could be doing wrong, when I console.log `postUser`, I do see the function passed as argument logged to the console, but when I try sending requests, it fails.

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some misconceptions here.

You're defining an interface `PostMethod`, which itself IS NOT a method. It is an interface. So if you try to pass an instance of this, please don't just pass a FUNCTION (or method). But pass an instance of `PostMethod`.

It could look like this (look at the changes I made):

```
export interface PostMethod {
  add: (req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<any> // not sure if it should be returning any
}

export class PostController implements PostMethod {
  constructor(public postMethod: any) {}

  async add(req: Request, res: Response) {
    // cloning? if so, do it like this
    let incomingHttpBody = { ...req.body }
    console.log('body', incomingHttpBody)
    console.log(this.postMethod)
    type Source = {
      ip: string
      browser: string | string[] | undefined
      referrer: string | string[]
    }
    let source = {} as Source
    source.ip = req.ip
    source.browser = req.headers['User-Agent']
    if (req.headers.Referer) {
      source.referrer = req.headers.Referer
    }

    // change: I made a change here, you have to call postMethod.add!
    const newItem = await this.postMethod.add({ source, ...incomingHttpBody })
    return apiResponse({
      status: true,
      statusCode: 201,
      message: 'Resource created successfully',
      data: [newItem]
    })
  }
}

// change: instantiate AddUser which in turn implements PostMethod that can be passed...
const postMethod = new AddUser(UsersDb)
export const postUser = new PostController(postMethod)

// change: implementing PostMethod!
export class AddUser implements PostMethod {
  constructor(public usersDb: UserDatabase) {}
  
  // change: new method! this is a must, because we're implementing PostMethod!
  async add(req: Request, res: Response) {
    // this gets called, not addUser!
  }

  async addUser(userInfo: IUser) {
    const exists = await this.usersDb.findByEmail(userInfo.email)
    if (exists) {
      throw new UniqueConstraintError('Email address')
    }
    const user = new UserFactory(userInfo)
    user.makeUser()
    const { email, ...details } = user.user
    const newUser = await this.usersDb.insert({ email, ...details })
    const id = newUser.user._id
    await createWallet(id)
    // await publisher(id.toString(), 'newuser.verify')
    // await consumer('verify_queue', verifyUser, '*.verify')
    return newUser
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope this brings you forward ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help, I see what you did there, but I was aiming to follow the Clean Code Architecture, hence why in my ``` class AddUser``` I didn't add ```req, res``` directly to it, Instead, I made a use-case of ```class AddUser``` which is then passed to the ```PostController Class```.to maintain separation of concern. Any chance, you could point me forward in a way to achieve this architecture like this? Many thanks :-)

Comment: I suggest, if it helped to solve the problem you described, you mark one answer as the right answer. Your goal with clean code and making it even better is not the topic here I think. I would say you open up another question for that and tag that one with things like "clean code" etc.

Comment: And of course I fully understand your aim with that, but personally I first solve my compile problems and then I try to clean up my code. Those are 2 separate tasks. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: you're right, it actually makes sense. Solve problems first,  then clean up code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class first before you can use the method...

```
...
const postMethod = new AddUser(UsersDb)

//then use it

postMethod.addUser()
export const postUser = new PostController(postMethod)

...
```

However you could make it static so you do not need to instantiate it:

```
static async add(req: Request, res: Response) { ....
```

An function is usually written like this in an interface:

```
export interface PostMethod {
  constructor(): void,
  add(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any>
}
```

Comment: This is not 100% true. "However you could make it static so you do not need to instantiate it" is true if you're only looking at the method. It wouldn't change the fact that the questionaire passed the method wrongly. I'll do my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, after much digging and reading up I realized it was a problem with `this` losing its context. Hence why I was getting undefined when I do something like this.

```
const postMethod = new PostController(usecase)
```

The fix was to bind this in the constructor like so,

```
this.add = this.add.bind(this)
```

that fixed the issue as when the class was instantiated it doesn't just point to the methods of the class but also the associations of the class.

Answer (score -1):

The postMethod parameter which is being passed into the constructor of PostMethod is not being stored anywhere. Store it ins a private class variable and then use the private class variable.

like -

```
const _postMethod = postMethod;
```

and then while calling call

```
const newItem = await this._postMethod({ source, ...incomingHttpBody })
```

Comment: There were plenty of errors in the original code, this is not the right solution.